# JsTree get html attribute from a node that is not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I have started working with JsTree and I am having trouble navigating nodes. I have a used a HTML list to create the tree view and all information is present on the page when creating the tree, there are no additional AJAX calls.

When selecting a parent node I wish to get the information from all children (some custom HTML attributes). When selecting the parent I use:

```
data.instance.get_node("[id='" + value + "']");
```

on the "changed.jstree" event which returns the node and all information I need (including all children) as a full jQuery object.

However, using the same line to get the information from a child when it is not drawn on screen (the parent is not expanded), returns "false", rather than a jQuery object.

When creating the JsTree I also use the following line to try and load all nodes when it is being created:

```
jQuery(controlSelector).jstree("load_all");
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get the information from a child node if it is not rendered and the parent is not expanded?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `children_d` property of selected node to grab id's of all its children. Check the code below and demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/y2stn0wm/).

```
var selectedNodes = $('#container').jstree().get_selected(true);

for(var i=0, len=selectedNodes.length; i<len; i++) {
    // access id's with selectedNodes[i].children_d ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can get the children ok, its the jQuery object of the children I have issues retrieving. When the parent is not expanded, if you use the ID of a child element to get a jQuery object of that child element, jQuery will only return the boolean value "false" rather than the information as the child is not drawn on screen. It is the jQuery object of a unrendered node I am trying to get.

Comment: What would you do with the jquery object of hidden node?

Comment: Get the custom HTML attributes I have added to the node, for each node I use: node.li_attr["data-type"]  to get some information I need to parse out. But the child nodes aren't rendered when they are hidden.

Comment: You don't need a jquery object for that. Just get the node by id with `var node = $('#container').jstree().get_node( selectedNodes[i].children_d[y] )`, where `y` is the index of the child in the second loop, and access the `li_attr` from there as `node.li_attr`

Comment: Yeah I used the get_node before but if it is not drawn on screen it seems to return "False". What I have done instead is loop through the "tree._model.data" with a conditional to what I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I afraid you didn't try out what I meant. Even if nothing is drawn, you can access it. Check it here - http://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/RaZXYX

Answer (score 0):

I have found all the unrendered data is stored in

```
jQuery("#container").jstree(true)._model.data
```

I then loop through all the nodes on the tree and match the node to a conditional statement I set up to retrieve what I need as calling:

```
tree.get_node("#value");
```

returns false if the node is not currently drawn on screen.